# How to create appropiated jsonschema validator from $schema keyword

Tags: python, jsonschema

The library https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/ implements validators for different drafts: Draft202012Validator, Draft201909Validator, etc.

My jsonschema contains the draft version:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
        .....
   }
}
```

Therefore, I have to import `Draft202012Validator`. But, other schemas may use another draft version. Instead to import the appropiated validator, would it be possible to read *$schema* and create the appropiated validator?

Answer (score 1):

That's [jsonschema.validators.validator_for](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/jsonschema/validators/#jsonschema.validators.validator_for).